# AS3 getter setter from sub class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I know this has been covered a lot, but I just can't seem to get it to work.

How do I listen from the main class to a sub class for a variable change?

```
package  {

    import flash.events.*

    public class DataBase extends MovieClip  {

        private var _OPPONENTTYPE:int = 0;

            public function DataBase() {
               OPPONENTTYPE(1);
            }
        public function get OPPONENTTYPE():int {
            return _OPPONENTTYPE;
        }
        public function set OPPONENTTYPE(num:int) {
            _OPPONENTTYPE = num;
            dispatchEvent(new Event(DataBase._OPPONENTTYPE));
        }
```

This is what I have so far for the sub class but I can't seem to figure out how to listen to this variable change from Main() or even if I am dispatching the event properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that Main has a reference to the Database class you could do something like this:

First, in Database declare a public const to hold the name of your event.  This is better than using a string in your event code because it allows editors to error check and auto-complete.

```
public static const DATABASE_CHANGE:String = "onDatabaseChange";
```

Now modify your setter to use this const:

```
public function set OPPONENTTYPE(num:int) {
    _OPPONENTTYPE = num;
    dispatchEvent(new Event(DataBase.DATABASE_CHANGE));
}
```

In Main you need to listen for the event (assuming that you have already instantiated and made a reference to Database):

```
databaseRef.addEventListener(Database.DATABASE_CHANGE,dbChangeHandler);
```

And finally, in the handler you check the new value of OPPONENTTYPE by looking at the target of the event object, which will be your database class, or by using the reference you used when setting up the listener:

```
private function dbChangeHandler(evt:Event):void
{
    //both lines output the same
    trace(evt.target.OPPONENTTYPE);
    trace(databaseRef.OPPONENTTYPE);
}
```

Comment: This looks great, one question before i try this, Can I keep public class DataBase extends MovieClip? or do I have to change it to extend eventDispatcher?

Comment: If database is not an uicomponent and using to dispatch event then it should be eventDispatcher, able to dispatch custom events

Comment: Getting this error: Line 63 1119: Access of possibly undefined property DATABASE_CHANGE through a reference with static type DataBase.
This is the affected line: `dbControl.addEventListener(dbControl.DATABASE_CHANGE,dbChangeHandler);` 
and I am instantiating database like so... `public var dbControl:DataBase = new DataBase();`

Comment: When you use that static to define an event String, you reference the actual class, not the instance you've created.  So `dbControl.addEventListener(dbControl.DATABASE_CHANGE,dbChangeHandler);` should be `dbControl.addEventListener(DataBase.DATABASE_CHANGE,dbChangeHandler);`.

Comment: No compiler errors. and I am making it to the set function with a trace statement inside of it. Only thing is, the eventlistener in main is not picking up the dispatched event. `dbControl.addEventListener(DataBase.DATABASE_CHANGE,dbChangeHandler);` I know we are close so I am accepting your answer before I go to work.

Comment: Because you're setting the property in the constructor of Database the property is being set before the listener is added.  You could either use a public init function in DataBase to set the property after you add the listener, or just call the event handler in Main after you add the listener to Database.

Comment: Thank you shanethehat, works perfectly, thank you for the clear and concise explanation.

Answer (score 1):

A good way of doing this is Create Custom Event Type for Variable Change

```
package  {  
    import flash.events.Event;
        public class VariableEvent extends Event{
            public var variableName:object;
            public var oldValue:object;
            public var newValue:object;
            static public var VALUE_CHANGE:String = "VALUE_CHANGE";

            public function VariableEvent(variableName:String, oldValue:object, newValue:object, bubbles:Boolean = false, cancelable:Boolean = false){
            super(VALUE_CHANGE, bubbles,cancelable);

            this.variableName = variableName;
            this.oldValue = oldValue;
            this.newValue = newValue;
        }
    }

}
```

Add Event Handler/Listener in MAIN Class which contains reference of 
**mydispatcher** as

```
mydispatcher.addEventListener(VariableEvent.VALUE_CHANGE, variableChangedListener);
```

and Handler function in MAIN Class will be

```
private function variableChangedListener(event:VariableEvent):void
    {
        Alert.show(event.variableName +"Changed From "+event.oldValue+" To "+event.newValue);
    }
```

Dispatch Event Like that on variable value change from mydispatcher

```
dispatchEvent(new VariableEvent("variableName",<old Value>, <changed/new Value>));
```

Hopes that helps